# Updating dataSource of layer in APRX map object

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers, data-source

I have the code below that updates the `connectionProperties` of a layer inside of a APRX Map should it meet certain criteria. All of this works fine, the connection properties are updated for all layers that should be.
However, the `dataSource` property of the layer does not change. this prevents the source of the data being updated in the APRX map. I am aware of the `replaceDataSource`  method in ArcMap but from what i have read this is only available at the mxd level or if the file is .lyr

How can I update the dataSource element of the layer in the map so that I can change the source featureclass (dataset) of the layer

```
final = ['Generator']
sld_layers = ['db.owner.Generator_SLD']
blank_layers = m.listLayers()
for l in blank_layers:
    if l.connectionProperties:
        dataset_name = l.connectionProperties['dataset'].split('.')[-1]
        if dataset_name in final:
            sld_two = 'db.owner.{}_SLD'.format(dataset_name)
            sld_one = 'db.owner.{}_SLD_ATTRIBUTES'.format(dataset_name)
            if sld_one in sld_layers:
                new_dataset = sld_one
            else:
                new_dataset = sld_two
            source_cp = l.connectionProperties
            destination_cp = source_cp
            destination_cp['connection_info']['dataset']=new_dataset
            destination_cp['dataset']=new_dataset
            l.updateConnectionProperties(source_cp, destination_cp)
            a.save()

        else:
            print("{} not in the sld data".format(dataset_name))
    else:
        print(l.name + " does not support connection properties")
```